# Consuming Discriminated Union types in variable bindings

Tags: types, f#, discriminated-union

I have made a custom type and would like to create 2 variables that prove my type works as expected.

```
type number = A of int | B of float;;

let a = 0;;
let b = 0.0;;
```

How should I change the variable declarations to force them to type `number`? Currently a is int and b is float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To force them to be type `number`, all you need to do is assign them to a value of type `number`.  The examples you give:

```
let a = 0
let b = 0.0
```

are assigning them to values of type `int` and `float` respectively.  To get values of type `number`, construct `number` objects from those values like this:

```
let a = A(0)
let b = B(0.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You just go:

```
let a = A(0)
let b = B(0.0)
```